# Finding matching motifs on sequence and their positions

Tags: python, position, bioinformatics, biopython, fasta

I am trying to find some matching motifs on a sequence, as well as the position that the motif is located in and then output that into a fasta file. The code below shows that the motif [L**L*L] is present in the sequence, when I run it returns as "YES" but I do not know where it is positioned

The ** inside the square bracket is to show that any amino acid there is permited.
`

This is the code I used to check whether the motif is present in the sequence, and it worked because it returned "YES".

```
peptide1= "MKFSNEVVHKSMNITEDCSALTGALLKYSTDKSNMNFETLYRDAAVESPQHEVSNESGSTLKEHDYFGLSEVSSSNSSSGKQPEKCCREELNLNESATTLQLGPPAAVKPSGHADGADAHDEGAGPENPAKRPAHHMQQESLADGRKAAAEMGSFKIQRKNILEEFRAMKAQAHMTKSPKPVHTMQHNMHASFSGAQMAFGGAKNNGVKRVFSEAVGGNHIAASGVGVGVREGNDDVSRCEEMNGTEQLDLKVHLPKGMGMARMAPVSGGQNGSAWRNLSFDNMQGPLNPFFRKSLVSKMPVPDGGDSSANASNDCANRKGMVASPSVQPPPAQNQTVGWPPVKNFNKMNTPAPPASTPARACPSVQRKGASTSSSGNLVKIYMDGVPFGRKVDLKTNDSYDKLYSMLEDMFQQYISGQYCGGRSSSSGESHWVASSRKLNFLEGSEYVLIYEDHEGDSMLVGDVPWELFVNAVKRLRIMKGSEQVNLAPKNADPTKVQVAVG"

if re.search(r"L*L*L", peptide1):
        print("YES")
else: 
    print("NO")
```

The code that I wrote to find the position is below, but when I run it says invalid syntax. Could you please assist as I have no clue whether in the right track or not, as I am still new in the field and python.

```
 for position in range(len(s)):
    if peptide[position:].startswith(r"L*L*L"):
        print(position+1)
```

I am expecting to see the position of these motifs has been identified, for example the output should state whether the motif is found in position [2, 10] or any other number. This is just random posiitions that I chose since I dont know where this is positioned

Comment: What is your motif supposed to mean? Asterisk are special characters in regex, meaning match 0 or more times. Right now, "L\*L\*L" mean to match "L" one or more times (written in a roundabout way). Asterisks also are generally interpreted as stop codons in biology. If you want to match the asterisk explicitly, you have to escape it with a forward slash: "L\\*L\\*L". But if you aren't pattern matching, it's best not to use regex.

Comment: @Ghoti, the motif is actually "LxLxL", where the x means it  can be any other amino acid in that space. I used an example online which did this, which used the asterisk to represent the "x" I have pasted the link below https://www.badgrammargoodsyntax.com/compbio/2017/12/3/compbio-014-practical-python-for-biologists-finding-motifs-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.finditer()` to search for multiple regex pattern matches within a string. Your `peptide1` example does not contain an "L*L*L" motif, so I designated a random simple string as a demo.

```
simple_demo_string = "ABCLXLYLZLABC" # use a simple string to demonstrate code
```

The demo string contains two overlapping motifs. Normally, regex matches do not account for overlap

**Example 1**

```
simple_regex = "L.L.L" # in regex, periods are match-any wildcards

for x in re.finditer(simple_regex, simple_demo_string):
    print( x.start(), x.end(), x.group() )

# Output: 3 8 LXLYL
```

However, if you use a capturing group inside a lookahead, you'll be able to get everything even if there's overlap.

**Example 2**

```
lookahead_regex = "(?=(L.L.L))"

for x in re.finditer(lookahead_regex, simple_demo_string):
    # note - x.end() becomes same as x.start() due to lookahead 
    # but can be corrected by simply adding length of match
    print( x.start(), x.start()+len(x.group(1)), x.group(1) )

# Output: 3 8 LXLYL
#.        5 10 LYLZL
```